# How to show the target location at a particular position of the map container

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I created a simple map like in this example from the Leaflet.js tutorial:

```
var map=L.map('map').setView([51.505,-0.09], 13);
```

Now, the target location is shown centered in the map.

My map container has a size of 600x400 pixels. How can I achieve to show the given target at a custom position within the container? Let's say I want the location to appear horizontally centered but 50 pixels from top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's easy to do using two utility methods of `L.Map` called [latLngToContainerPoint](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-latlngtocontainerpoint) and it's counterpart [containerPointToLatLng](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-containerpointtolatlng).

```
// Get LatLng position of the marker
var oldLatLng = marker.getLatLng();
// Convert LatLng to containerpoint in pixels.
var oldPoint = map.latLngToContainerPoint(oldLatLng);
// Calculate new point 
var newPoint = L.point(oldPoint.x, oldPoint.y + (oldPoint.y - 50));
// Convert point to LatLng
var newLatLng = map.containerPointToLatLng(newPoint);
// Set new map view
map.setView(newLatLng);
```

Here's a working example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/8y5Klz?p=preview